# How to implement Secure Connection to SAP HANA Database through JDBC?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, hana

I am able to connect to HANA database through my server using JDBC. I am trying to figure out if my connection to the database is secured or not?

```
        public void createDataSource() {
            DataSource dataSource =  DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(JDBC_DRIVER)
            .URL("jdbc:sap://localhost:30013/?encrypt=true&validateCertificate=true")
            .username("username")
            .password("password")
            .build();
          
            Connection c = dataSource.getConnection();  
      }
```

Now what I have understood from Documentation is that when I set parameters in the URL such

> encrypt=true

It enables or disables TLS encryption.
For SAP HANA Cloud connections to succeed, encrypt must be set to TRUE.

Another parameter is:

> validateCertificate=true

If set to true, specifies that the server’s certificate is validated.

Here I am not able to understand is when it will be deployed to production is this all we need to do for a secure database connection? Can someone please point out what I am missing?

Comment: If you use those parameters, the connection *should* be secure ... provided that nobody has leaked the private key used to create the certificate.  (Actually ... I don't understand what you are missing.  Perhaps you should explain why you think it wouldn't be secure.  Then maybe we can tell you what you are missing.)

Comment: Hi, 
@Stephen C  Thank you for replying.  I was wondering that when I say encrypt=true then what is happening internally? I mean how the parameters helping here to encrypt or validate the certificate. Thanks again

Comment: They >tell< the driver to use encryption and validate the certificate. If you really need to know what is happening internally, you will need to get the source code for the driver and perform a security analysis on it.  Talk to the software vendor.

Comment: Or ... you can check out the FIPS certification for the product; see https://help.sap.com/viewer/b8eac28c172c4538b569c29e5fda69f9/16.0.4/en-US/b2632d37bbf9101495f4ad0d6e7292d1.html

Comment: Thanks, @StephenC, I will read more on this. Thank you for your clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neat thing about certificates is that you normally don't have to worry about them.

The java virtual machine (JVM) ships with a set of so-called root certificates of the certificate authorities (CAs) (including the DigiCert Global Root CA). Depending on the java distribution there might be slight differences, but the top CAs should be trusted by all.

You can see the list of trusted CAs with the following command:

keytool -list -v -cacerts -storepass changeit

As long as the SSL certificate of your database is signed by one of these CAs (or an intermediate of these) you don't need any additional configuration and it just works out of the box. This is as well the scenario, which you should aim for as it is the easiest.

You can however as well pass to the JVM your own list of trusted certificates or, and this is probably for a generic set up the best, set a custom truststore for a single JDBC connection. In a dockerized setup, you can e.g. make the whole database string configurable allowing people to mount their own CAs into the container and configure them in the database connection string. For details check the SAP documentation on the "JDBC Connection Properties for SAP HANA".

jdbc:sap://localhost:30013/?encrypt=true&validateCertificate=true&trustStore=file:cert/truststore.jks&trustStorePassword=123456